# What does "LZ" mean?

Tags: tenet

Wheeler briefing Red and Blue Team:

> Wheeler: Everybody, look to your left. If you are not at the **LZ** at
> zero, you are not leaving.

What does "LZ" mean?

Comment: Landing zone...

Comment: It's a military term for: *Landing zone*

Comment: @Valorum. Sorry answers crossed in the post.

Comment: @PEW  - Not to worry. I declined to answer because this one isn't really about scifi,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LZ conventionally means Landing Zone. Watched the film at the weekend so I would hazard a guess that is the meaning in this context.